# Restore iOS 10 backup to an old iPhone 4s

Tags: backup, iphone, ios

I just broke my iPhone 5s running iOs 10.1.1 and I would like to restore a back-up to an old iPhone 4s that I own.

iTunes claims that the iOS version is too recent to restore it. Is there a way to tweak/downgrade the backup in order to avoid using the iCloud backup?

Answer (score 3):

You can't restore a backup of a newer iOS version to an older iOS version.

However, you can examine the contents of the backup using [iBackupBot](http://www.icopybot.com/itunes-backup-manager.htm) and then manually restore what you can using iBackupBot's restore mechanism. This won't restore incompatible databases such as your messages, but you can usually restore app data.

Comment: I'll take a look!